# how to format text in java script in rails apps

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a  with id  this is logic so here i am sending text dynamically now i want to resize and recolour this text. my jquery look like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function($){
 $("#daily_type").change(function()
{
  logic = $(this).val()

  LogicShow(logic)
})
function LogicShow(logic)
{

  if ( logic == "iss" )
  {
    var spanText = "Based on the severity High" ;
    $("#logic_change").html(spanText);
  }
  if ( logic == "unix" )
  {
    var spanText = "Summary reflects based on the number of events.Such as how many times number of events observed" ;
    $("#logic_change").html(spanText);
  }

}
});

</script>
```

so now how can i pass text with some good text format and colour.

Comment: Question is quiet confusing,can u add little more please? where you want to pass the text?

Comment: here i am passing text in <td> by the help of jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving a `class` with a `span` wrapping.

```
var spanText = '<span class="logictext">Based on the severity High</span>' ;
```

And then wrote css for those `class`es.

Or you can give inline css as well:

```
var spanText = '<span style="color: #f00;">Based on the severity High</span>' ;
```

Comment: here i am using <td> element of html.

Comment: @samarth then use `td` instead of `span`